How to create list bill account in BillingCenter using cloud API?
We want to create a list bill account in Billingcenter using the cloud api. We are using the correct endpoint to create an account but looks like there is no attribute in the request to set the payment plan on the account. Since, payment plan is mandatory for a list bill account, our call is failing with the exception that the list bill account should have a payment plan. We do see other plans are there in the OOTB request. We are using the /accounts post request in one of the Billingcenter apis.
Is List bill account creation not supported OOTB? We do see an attribute "Account type" in the request.

Maybe the Guidewire community or a support ticket would be the right platform to ask questions on new or missing features.

My assumption would be to use the AccountType field in the body and then handle the ListBill value within the code operation inside of the BillingApiExtHandler class you can route the call to create a ListBill company and set the correct information on the ListBill Account at that level. Use the relevant data sent in the body but set the correct payment plans in a separate logic block
